# How to strip user defined tags from a string in php?

Tags: string, strip-tags

For example:

```
$str="<name>ABCDE<age>45";
```

I know the use of `strip_tags` function,it reomves all the tags in the sring. But I want to strip only a particular tag to get the output as  `"ABCDE<age>45";`

Is it possible?

Comment: you can use strip_tags to set allowed tags as second parameter or use regex...
do you want to KEEP text between tags or just remove all tags or just remove anything BETWEEN tags?
i'll provide a solution then.

Comment: you can pass second parameter, allowable tags

Comment: check my answer and let me know if i m lagging anywhere

Comment: @Registered User your answer is not applicable in my question.

Comment: just add the <age> there is a comment before the strip_tags to unferstand

Comment: @Mihai Iorga Is it possible to get out put as "ABCDE".

Comment: @SujathanR yes it is possible see my answer now

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the task as follows. Thanks for all your useful answers.

```
$str_arr==preg_split("/<[^>]+>/", $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Output:

```
$str_arr[0]=ABCDE
$str_arr[1]=45
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this by [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) it Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

```
  // Allow <p> and <a>
      echo strip_tags($str, '<p><a>');

  $str="<name>ABCDE<age>45";
```

from your comment  **Is it possible to get out put as "ABCDE" ?** ,
yes it is possible this can be done by either `substr` or `preg_match`

```
  echo substr($str,6,8); to get only ABCDE
```

or

you can do this by [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$pattern = '/^ABCDE/';
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 5);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Hi @Registered User, the main problem with your answer is ,"ABCDE" is just an example ,in the real case it may be a large string,then I cant count the substring position.Please answer in a generalized way.

Comment: @SujathanR then you can use the [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 0):

use `strip_tags()` with `allowable_tags`:

```
$str="<name>ABCDE<age>45";
echo strip_tags($str, '<age>');
```

[Codepad Example](http://codepad.org/q0jIPtgK)

Comment: It's not working.it gives me the same result as strip_tags gives,ABCDE45.

Comment: I do believe you are not looking at the source from the outputted content, but it works.

Comment: @Mihai Iorga Ya it still not gives me the right answer,believe me bro :-)

Comment: @Mihai Iorga Ya,It's seems working.But it didn't work in my system.Is this related to any php.ini configuration.Please advice.

Comment: @Mihai Iorga.ok I wil check it more deeply,and will inform you later.

Comment: @Mihai Iorga.Hi I have checked the code in my browser it gives me ABCDE45.Then I took the page view source ,it displays ABCDE<age>45.What I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tags you wish to delete in an array and then delete it. For example:

```
$string = "<name>ABCDE<age>45";
$custom_tags = array('name');
$tags_length = sizeof($custom_tags);
for ($i = 0; $i < $tags_length; $i++) {
    $string = str_replace("<" . $custom_tags[$i] . ">", "", $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation of **[strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)**

string strip_tags ( string $str **[, string $allowable_tags ]** )

You can allow some tags if you want : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php.
May the optional parameter, **[, string $allowable_tags ]**, can solve your problem ? !

Comment: what is meaning off "I know you know it but I don't understand the question"

Comment: I want to say that I've read what he wrote, "I know the use of strip_tags function"... but it seems that he don't know it, strip_tags function, very well.
Sorry for bad expression.